# R: Rvest read_html() Error: invalid multibyte string, element 2

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I try to scrape webpages and I have a problem with the following page:
"https://www.federalreserve.gov/boarddocs/speeches/1998/19980828.htm"

Every time I try to load it into R I get the following Error message.

```
library(rvest)

page <- read_html( "https://www.federalreserve.gov/boarddocs/speeches/1998/19980828.htm")
> page
{html_document}
<html>
Error in nchar(desc) : invalid multibyte string, element 2
```

I already searched a lot for solutions and tried the following approaches:

-) Changing the encoding from "UTF-8" to "ISO-8859-1" or "latin1" -> I can now load the page into R but it does not contain any text only empty paragraphs

-) I set "Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "English")" or "Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "en_US.UTF-8")", but it does not change anything.

I am a bit helpless right now. Maybe you could help me out or give me new ideas.

Best Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is a fatal error the parser can't recover from (see testing with https://validator.w3.org/). Fix the html first and then parse.

[test](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.federalreserve.gov%2Fboarddocs%2Fspeeches%2F1998%2F19980828.htm)

[image]

An example package to assist with fixing would be `htmltidy`:

```
library(htmltidy)
library(rvest)

page <- read_html( "https://www.federalreserve.gov/boarddocs/speeches/1998/19980828.htm") %>% 
  toString() %>% 
  tidy_html() %>% 
  read_html()

page %>% 
  html_node('title') %>% 
  html_text()
```

Comment: Unfortunately even accounting for this issue does not help with scraping the text context of the webpage. The text is withint a <td> tag and seperated by <p> tags, which is utterly disturbing. Anyways the fixed html document does only contain the tables at the end of the page but no text. I will report the faulty page to them and solve it manually until it is fixed.